# How do I return 8.0 instead of 8 when using streams?

Tags: c++, ostream

The formatting and output of this code matches the sample output of my assignment, but the issue is that I am returning `8` when I want it to be `8.0`.

What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void runningSum(istream &in, ostream &out)
{
    string line, str;
    double sum = 0, max = 0;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        istringstream sin(line);
        out << "running sum = ";
        while (sin >> str)
        {
            sum = sum + stod(str);
            out << sum << " ";

            if(max < sum) max = sum;
        }
        out << "\nmax sum = " << max << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in("in.txt");
    runningSum(in, cout);
    return 0;
}
// in.txt: 3.25 4.5 -8.25 7.25 3.5 4.25 -6.5 5.25
// my output:
// running sum = 3.25 7.75 -0.5 6.75 10.25 14.5 8 13.25
// max sum = 14.5
// desired output:
// running sum = 3.25 7.75 -0.5 6.75 10.25 14.5 8.0 13.25
// max sum = 14.5
```

Comment: Please insert the expected and actual result as text and not as image!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I added them just now in the comments under my main function if that's fine.

Comment: The thing is, that you "posted" an image, but you should use text instead. Same goes for errors and code (which you gladly not did! <3 ). For rational see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @QuanDo yes that's fine.

Comment: Why do you want it to be shown as 8.0? Is this a requirement in your assignment?

Comment: Note that you don't have to stream into `str` and then convert to double, you can stream directly into a double variable. `for (double value; sin >> value;) { /* use value */ }`

Comment: Yes, the 8.0 is necessary. Points will be deducted if I do not account for that.

Comment: Will points be deducted if you have `-0.50` and `8.00` etc?

Comment: Yes, my professor is firm with the output as he uses a python script to test the assignments without having to manually grade them so I am not receiving 100% of the points due to this one error. @Caleth

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you but if the requirement is to matchbthe sample output character to character, then your educators are incompetent idiots. Now that we have this unpleasant truth out of the way, the easiest way to match the sample output would be to check each number you output, and if it's close enough to an integer, output `.0` as text right after the number.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of checking with an if-else statement and with setprecision as that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: setprecision sets the total number of digits (before and after the decimal point). You can try it but it's not that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fairly sensible, the requirement is just slightly tricky.

What I suggest is to write a function to format `double`s in the desired form, adding a trailing ".0" if necessary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

std::string format(double value)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    // check for existing decimal point
    if (ss.str().find('.') == std::string::npos)
    {
        ss << ".0";
    }
    return ss.str();
}

void runningSum(istream &in, ostream &out)
{
    for (std::string line; getline(in, line);)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(); // could be always negative
        std::istringstream sin(line);
        out << "running sum = ";
        for (double value; sin >> value;)
        {
            sum += value;
            out << format(sum) << " ";

            max = std::max(max, sum);
        }
        out << "\nmax sum = " << format(max) << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    runningSum(in, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *slightly tricky* It looks like you misspelled "totally moronic". Your code [doesn't match it all that well](https://ideone.com/c3O04Q).You need something rather exceeding your typical beginner's knowledge for that.

Comment: I'll agree with "totally moronic" if the prof wants an exact passthrough of a decimal number that's not representable in IEEE 754. All of the examples are binary fractions

Comment: The prof allegedly wants to match his favourite output format, which cannot be expressed directly in C++. This forces students to focus on useless minutiae instead of learning important skills. This is why the requirement is moronic. The problem is not with decimal numbers not representable in IEEE 754, the problem is that the default output format *rounds* numbers (which are representable in IEEE 754 --- you can't get your hands on anything else). So the simplistic check `value == std::floor(value)` is inadequate.

Comment: There's often business requirements to *display* in a specified format, and it's useful to learn to push that to the edges of a system. And when you are **reading in text**, you certainly *can* get unrepresentable decimals

Comment: Anyway, switched the check to a string find.